# How to update multiple records with multiple values in mongo db and node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have few records in mongo db and i need to update all those records with different values at a single stretch which matches its "id".

The record in mongo db will not have value for "status" & "timestamp" and i need to update these.
When i try to update the record, the update values are getting newly inserted into another new collection and not updating in my existing collection.

```
var parsedRes = [{
            "id": "1000000",
            "mobilenum": "2323442343",
            "code": "SC0",          
            "status": "1",
            "timestamp": "1602771846"
        }, {
            "id": "1000001",
            "mobilenum": "3323442343",
            "code": "SC0",           
            "status": "8",
            "timestamp": "1602771843"
        }, {
            "id": "1000002",
            "mobilenum": "4323442343",
            "code": "SC0",
            "status": "3",
            "timestamp": "1602771842"
        }, {
            "id": "1000003",
            "mobilenum": "5323442343",
            "code": "SC0",
            "status": "1",
            "timestamp": "1602771844"
        } 
    ]

    var updateData = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < parsedRes.length; i++) {

        updateData.push({
            updateOne: {
                filter: { ID: parsedRes[i].id },
                update: {
                    $set: {
                        mobile: parsedRes[i].mobilenum,
                        code: parsedRes[i].code,
                        status: parsedRes[i].status,
                        timestamp: parsedRes[i].timestamp
                    }
                }, upsert: true
            }
        });
      }
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          mongomodel.bulkWrite(updateData, { ordered: false }, async function(err, result) {   
              if (err) {
                  console.log("errorrrrrrrr : ",err)
                  reject(err)
              } else {
                  console.log("result :   ****************** ",result)
                  resolve(result)
              }
          })
          updateData = [];
      })
```

Could anyone please help me on where i go wrong. Is there any other approach to do this, please share. Thanks in advance.

sample document from db:
@wak786 Please find the sample document

```
db.mongomodel.find()

{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f896c9d1148a810d90a8261"), "id" : "1000000", "status" : "1", "mobilenum" : "2323442343", "code" : "TA0","UpdateDate" : "1602771841", "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-10-16T09:49:17.693Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-10-16T09:49:17.693Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f896c9d1148a810d90a8262"), "id" : "1000001", "status" : "8", "mobilenum" : "3323442343", "code" : "OR0","UpdateDate" : "1602771841", "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-10-16T09:49:17.693Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-10-16T09:49:17.693Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f896c9d1148a810d90a8263"), "id" : "1000002", "status" : "1", "mobilenum" : "4323442343", "code" : "OC0","UpdateDate" : "1602771841", "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-10-16T09:49:17.693Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-10-16T09:49:17.693Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f896c9d1148a810d90a8264"), "id" : "1000003", "status" : "1", "mobilenum" : "5323442343", "code" : "TC0","UpdateDate" : "1602771841", "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-10-16T09:49:17.693Z"), "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-10-16T09:49:17.693Z") }
```

Comment: Can you post some sample documents from db.

Comment: @wak786 , I have addded the sample document by edting the question as its not allowing me to give more characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the things I notice here are :

1. You are using `upsert:true`. It will add new documents to collection if your filter query doesn't find any matching documents. SO setting `upsert:false` will solve the problem of new documents getting added to collection.
2. Another problem I suspect is in following line of code.

```
filter: { ID: parsedRes[i].id },
```

I think it should be `id` instead of ID (I am assuming it is not a Javascript constant).
If you have `const ID = "id"` somewhere in your code then ignore this point.

**EDIT :-**

Can you try by removing `$set` becoz what I see in latest mongoose docs, `$set` is not needed anymore.

This is from mongoose docs.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.bulkWrite

```
   {
    updateOne: {
      filter: { name: 'Eddard Stark' },
      // If you were using the MongoDB driver directly, you'd need to do
      // `update: { $set: { title: ... } }` but mongoose adds $set for
      // you.
      update: { title: 'Hand of the King' }
    }
  },
```

Comment: I have changed to upsert:false, now it didnt create new collection. but it s still not updating the records

Comment: HAve you also tried changing `ID` to `id` like so `filter: { id: parsedRes[i].id }`

Comment: ya @wak786. I changed that as well. still the same issue.

Comment: Which version of mongoose are you using?

Comment: i m not getting any error, instead getting the resut as success, but no updation happening. my mongo version is 4.2.7

Comment: Not mongo, mongoose version? Anyways I am updating answer as per latest mongoose docs.

Comment: i changed the model name and tried... it wprked perfect. Thanks for the help @wak786